# How to get the url of the entry in which an image belongs

Tags: php, images, id

I'm creating a custom attachment template in WordPress, so far so good, but I would like to show the url of the entries or articles where that image belongs

somehow?

```
<div class="entry-attachment">
                <?php if (wp_attachment_is_image($post->id)) :
                    $att_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->id, "full"); ?>
                    <p class="attachment"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->id); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="attachment"><img src="<?php echo $att_image[0];?>" width="<?php echo $att_image[1];?>" height="<?php echo $att_image[2];?>"  class="attachment-medium" alt="<?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?>" /></a><figcaption class="captiont">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt); // displays the image caption ?> </figcaption>
                    </p>
```

Comment: The `$attachment_post->post_parent` is the post where it is used as a featured media. I wouldn't know how to get ALL the posts where it is used using the core methods. I think a custom data base query is needed

Comment: i believe this is not correct.  Afaik, the post parent of an attachment is the page that was open, if any, when the file was dragged and dropped into a media library modal.  Getting the usages of an image is not easy unless you only need to find where its used as a featured image.  depending on how the theme and plugins are coded its often not possible to truly get all usages.